# Howto dynamically generate function clauses

Tags: macros, elixir, metaprogramming

I need to dynamically generate function clauses, basing on the user’s config. For the sake of clarity, imagine I have a list of atoms:

```
@atoms ~w|foo bar baz|a
```

Coming from, say, `config.exs`. What I need is to generate this function (the MCVE is oversimplified, but it gives an impression on what I actually need):

```
@checker fn
  {:foo, _} -> false
  {:bar, _} -> false
  {:baz, _} -> false
  _ -> true
end
```

What I am currently doing is:

```
@clauses Enum.map(@atoms, fn tag ->
  {:->, [], [[{:{}, [], [tag, {:_, [], Elixir}]}], false]}
end) ++ [{:->, [], [[{:_, [], Elixir}], true]}]

defmacrop checker, do: {:fn, [], @clauses}
```

It works pretty fine, but I expect I am overcomplicating things, missing something simple. So, my question is:

**Is there an easy way to generate the function clauses in compile time?**

Comment: A good example of generating function clauses at compile time is here: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/base.ex lines 95-114

Comment: @DavidWhitlock this is an example of generating _many function declarations on top level_, it has nothing to do with what I am asking. I have no problems generating different `def`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it somewhat (see below for more) more readable using `quote`:

```
defmodule A do
  @atoms ~w|foo bar baz|a
  @clauses Enum.flat_map(@atoms, fn tag ->
    quote do: ({unquote(tag), _} -> false)
  end) ++ quote(do: (_ -> true))

  defmacro checker, do: {:fn, [], @clauses}
end

defmodule B do
  require A
  f = A.checker
  IO.inspect f.({:foo, :ok})
  IO.inspect f.({:bar, :ok})
  IO.inspect f.({:baz, :ok})
  IO.inspect f.({:quux, :ok})
end
```

Output:

```
false
false
false
true
```

---

I expected `quote(do: a -> b)` to work, but it's a parse error right now so we have to do `quote(do: (a -> b))` which wraps the quoted fragment we want in a list.

I also expected `unquote` to work inside `fn` when it's inside `quote`, but that also doesn't.

```
iex(1)> quote do
...(1)>   fn
...(1)>     unquote()
...(1)>     _ -> true
...(1)>   end
...(1)> end
** (SyntaxError) iex:2: expected clauses to be defined with -> inside: 'fn'
```

I believe these two are either bugs or missing features.

Comment: `quote(do: (a -> b))` wow :) I have tried with `quote(do: a -> b)` and gave up. I also tried unquoting inside the quoted code, there seems to matter a wrong precedence (syntax check _before_ `unquote`). Yes, this is slightly easier to read, but still I would like to wait for an answer with more magic. Upvoted, will accept after 2 days + bounty + 1 week.